# Is there a preferred way for creating a draw feature in a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I want to be able to draw circles on picture at a mouseclick or touch on a display. I also want to remove given circles if they're clicked/touched again. I know how to check if a given coordinate is within a circle. The problem is that I don't know the best approach to this task. Atm I'm using HTML5 canvas to draw circles with the .stroke() function, but I don't know how to "store" these circles so I can remove them if the'yre clicked/touched again. Is there a better solution than canvas available, or am I even approaching the problem the right way?

Comment: Have you considered using SVG instead? All elements are in the DOM, you can even attach event handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution based on SVG instead of canvas. There is a benefit you might consider: it is easy to store and retrieve, as it is self-describing.

```js
makeSVG = (tag, attrs) => {
    let el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
    for (var k in attrs) el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
    return el;
}

$(() => { 
  let $svg = $('svg')
  
  $('svg image').on('click', e => {
    let x = e.pageX - $svg.offset().left;
    let y = e.pageY - $svg.offset().top;
    
    var circle= makeSVG('circle', {cx: x, cy: y, r:40, stroke: 'black', 'stroke-width': 2, fill: 'red'});
    
    $svg.append(circle);
  })
  
  $('svg').on('click', 'circle', e => {
    $(e.currentTarget).remove()
  })
})
```

```css
html, body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <image xlink:href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" height="100%" width="100%"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I agree that this is a better solution! However I now have trouble scaling the circles with the browser size. When I adjust the browser size, the circles stay at the exact same position, and this is troublesome if I'm viewing the page on different devices. After looking around I think viewBox may be a solution, but I'm not having any luck so far.